# Error in Perl installation

Tags: installation, centos, perl

I have removed the pre-installed Perl and am trying to re-install it. But when I open a file with vim, I get an error like:

> error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And when I try to re-install, I get:

> perl: symbol lookup error: ../lib/auto/Time/HiRes/HiRes.so: undefined symbol: clock_gettime.

Please help me in this.

Comment: what OS? How did you install perl? How did you remove it?

Comment: I am using CentOS. and I have removed the perl by deleting all the files in /usr/lib/perl.

Comment: ugh, that is probably VERY bad. You should use the package manager for such things

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. now I have configured Perl in other location and installed mod_perl. But when I start apache, again error displays like Cannot load ../perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.9/i686-linux/Apache2/mod_perl.so into server: libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Comment: Try `yum provides "*/mod_perl.so"` and make sure you have installed all perl modules. Does the mod_perl.so file exist?

Comment: mod_perl.so file exists in teh paths /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_perl.so and ../perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.9/i686-linux/Apache2/mod_perl.so.

Comment: I have edited httpd.conf file like LoadModule perl_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_perl.so and then restarted the apache. Again the same error is displaying

Comment: Quite frankly, considering quite a lot of stuff in centos relies on perl, deleting it was not the best idea. Starting from scratch might be a brilliant idea.